# Run a python script just after run server django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a python script with indefinite loop it keeps in checking for the data, now I am confused how do I execute it so that it keeps running if the server is running. 
I think the script should run just after I run server in django but how do I run this script? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[django-admin runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver) is only for development use. Assuming this is a development environment, probably simplest to just run your script in a separate console, or make a simple shell script that starts the django server, backgrounds that process, then runs your script.

```
#!/bin/sh
django-admin runserver &
/path/to/my/script.py &
```

You'll need to kill those processes manually before re-running that script.

In a production environment, use [WSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/) to run Django and something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to run the other script. You could configure the OS init system (probably systemd) to ensure both of these tasks start on reboot and remain running.

Answer (score 0):

The first big part is to pack your indefinite loop into a function, and use huey/celery/etc to make it a 'task' that runs asynchronously.Then, call this task to run in your views.py/models.py/manage.py.

HOW TO LET THE TASK RUN ASYNCLY:

HUEY:[https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/]

HOW TO RUN THE TASK WHEN YOU START THE SERVER (2 ways):

1. Edit your manage.py ,add your function call at the line right behind the import of manage.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

print('Interesting things happens.') # THIS IS WHERE YOU RUN YOUR tasks.checkdata.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'OTAKU.settings')

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

2. However , maybe you want to leave the manage.py alone. Create a new app in your project, with views.py and models.py.(Remember to add this app to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py)

In views.py :

```
print("The view is loading.")# THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN RUN YOUR tasks.checkdata.
```

In models.py:

```
print("The models is loading.")# THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN RUN YOUR tasks.checkdata.
```

And when you run your server now, this is what you might see:

```
Interesting things happens.
The models is loading.
Interesting things happens.
The models is loading.
Performing system checks...

The view is preparing itself.
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 15, 2019 - 11:52:03
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'rayos.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:9988/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Replace the print part of the script with your data checking functions and it will work.

Comment: By following this as my loop is infinite it is stopping the server to start

Comment: If you pack your infinite loop in a huey task as the first step do,, it won't stop you from starting the server.The task that you pack would be running in a single thread/process/taskpool due to your config.

Comment: why don't we use threading in `manage.py`, like `thread.start(infinite_loop_fun)`

Comment: @Kamil Good point. using thread would be a light weight solution, while using an existed frame like huey or celery would make it easier if there's some other demand(for example, both framwork mentioned above allow user to choose whether we async the task using a real process or greenlet or else..)